# Return last year value with last_value function in SQL

Tags: sql, partition-by

I need to return the last value of the last date of the year. the problem is that the last value that already comes in SQL is being returned.

| Product | Date | Value | Last_Value_Previous_Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prod A | 31/12/2020 | 5000.00 | 2000.00 |
| Prod A | 01/01/2020 | 2000.00 | 2000.00 |
| Prod A | 01/01/2021 | 1000.00 | 3000.00 |
| Prod A | 01/02/2021 | 1500.00 | 3000.00 |
| Prod A | 01/03/2021 | 1000.00 | 3000.00 |
| Prod A | 01/04/2021 | 3000.00 | 3000.00 |

I need:

| Product | Date | Value | Last_Value_Previous_Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prod A | 31/12/2020 | 5000.00 | 5000.00 |
| Prod A | 01/01/2020 | 2000.00 | 5000.00 |
| Prod A | 01/01/2021 | 1000.00 | 3000.00 |
| Prod A | 01/02/2021 | 1500.00 | 3000.00 |
| Prod A | 01/03/2021 | 1000.00 | 3000.00 |
| Prod A | 01/04/2021 | 3000.00 | 3000.00 |

For the year 2020 it is returning the value of the last date that appears, when it should be the last of the year. I already tried to use the query

```
select 
    last_value(value) over (partition by Product order by to_char(date, 'YYYY')) 
from table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will work in Oracle.

```sql
SELECT          PRODUCT, 
                DATA, 
                VALUE, 
                LAST_VALUE(VALUE)
OVER (
  PARTITION BY  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(DATA,'DD-MM-YYYY')) 
  ORDER BY      EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(DATA,'DD-MM-YYYY')) 
)               AS LAST_VALUE
FROM            your_table
```

Comment: still not working, what could be wrong? @Florin

Comment: @ Luciano Amaro
I use your data in oracle and give the output you want it,in the last value function order by year not by date.if not even now is not working let me know and i will try again.What database are you using?

Comment: Oracle Database, it just returns the same value as the line itself, without any separation @Florin

Comment: @Luciano Amaro i try once again with your data and it works fain but probably you have more then one product a.so in this case do also a partition by product.let me know.thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would add `to_char(date,'YYYY')` in the partition by statement to group by product + year and ensure you'll have the latest value of the year, then order by date instead of year (actually, ordering by year will not really sort data).

Thus, you could try this :

```sql
select Product, Date, last_value(value) over (partition by Product, to_char(date,'YYYY') order by date)
  from table
```

Comment: this way returns me the value of the date itself @Christophe

Comment: Oh my bad, you might need to add the product itself and dates, at least (I just updated my answer accordingly)

Comment: still not working, what could be wrong? @Christophe

Comment: As I don't know, I wonder... is the `date` column correctly used, with an uppercase or not? I wonder, and it's the opportunity to advise you really NOT use keywords as column names, you'll always have doubts!
What is your result with this code?

Comment: The column date is not keyword. It just returns the same value as the line itself, without any separation @Christophe

Comment: what do you mean with "without any separation"?